# Apache POI stops working after 20 lines

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI for cell formatting (to color cells) but after 20 lines the others are without background color.

Here is my code:

```
        Cell c = null;
        //Cell pleine
        CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
        cs.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIME.index);
        cs.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        // cs.setFont(font);

        //Cell vide
        CellStyle csvide = wb.createCellStyle();
        csvide.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
        csvide.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        HSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        int rownum = sheet1.getLastRowNum() + 1;

        Row row = sheet1.createRow(rownum);
        //Row row1 = sheet1.createRow(1);
        Num++;
        c = row.createCell(0);
        c.setCellValue("⇢ " + Num + "  " + orderName + " ⇠ ");
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row.createCell(1);
        c.setCellValue("\uD83D\uDCC5" + NameDate);
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row.createCell(2);
        c.setCellValue("⏰" + NameHeure);
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        //  String mess = getResources().getString(R.string.Cell14);
        //String test =R.string.Cell14;

        c = row.createCell(3);
        //c.setCellValue("✘ NON ✘");
        c.setCellValue(getResources().getString(R.string.Cell14));
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row.createCell(4);
        c.setCellValue("");
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row.createCell(5);
        c.setCellValue("");
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row.createCell(6);
        c.setCellValue(NameDateNew);
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row.createCell(7);
        c.setCellValue(NameHeureNew);
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row.createCell(8);
        c.setCellValue("");
        c.setCellStyle(csvide);

        c = row.createCell(9);
        c.setCellValue("");
        c.setCellStyle(csvide);

        c = row.createCell(10);
        c.setCellValue("");
        c.setCellStyle(csvide);

        c = row.createCell(11);
        c.setCellValue("");
        c.setCellStyle(csvide);
```

Again, after twenty lines, the cells are no longer colored. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Follow the instructions in the docs, and create your cell styles outside the loop?

Comment: Hello, after what loop you think that we should put it? Thank you

Comment: I find that the problem comes from my second CellStyle ... if I removed I have no more problem ... with you two ideas of how to CellStyle?